# Which File contains the Bytecode Instruction Set of the OpenJDK 8

Tags: bytecode, java

i am new to openJDK8, i want to locate the file(s) where the **bytecode instruction set** is present which is used to **generate the bytecode** of a source .java file.
Secondly i need basic knowledge of the bytecode generation and execution process.

i am a research student and working on openJDK bytecode. Can you please guide?

Comment: [Tried googling](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077233/core-java/bytecode-basics.html)?)

Comment: yes. not found some direct answer.

Comment: Unclear what you're talking about exactly, but it sounds like a compiler component. Not necessarily a single source file either. The rest is far too broad. Study the JVM Specification and the JLS for a start, and compiler construction.

Comment: @EJP, as a **test case** i have to create a new bytecode instruction. which might be equivalent to any old instruction.

Comment: That doesn't actually clarify why you think you need to locate a specific source file.

Comment: I think you should start with the “i need basic knowledge of the bytecode generation and execution process” premise. Further, you should understand that the JVM, at least the one you can download from Oracle, is a compiled native software that doesn’t have a definition file that can be altered at runtime. To extend the JVM, even if you’re only heading for the interpreter, you have to download the entire source code, modify it and build a new JVM.

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to be conflating/mixing a number of different things. If you are creating a new bytecode there's several things you need to do.

- Specify/define the bytecode
- Modify the compiler to generate that bytecode
- Modify the runtime to understand that bytecode

The Java bytecodes are specified in the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11). If you need to define a new one, you need to specify it to a similar degree, though you don't have to publish it there.

The part of Java SDK that is responsible from taking Java source code and producing Java bytecode is the Java compiler (`javac`). The source code for OpenJDK's javac is available [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/langtools/file/d3aec746a8d2/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac). The source code for Eclipse's Java Compiler is also available, but I don't know where.

Once you have the java compiler generating your custom bytecode, you have to teach the JVM how to interpret it.

The OpenJDK VM (hotspot) has several components that handle executing the bytecode. There's more than one interpreter (that reads and executes bytecode) and multiple Just-In-Time optimizing compilers that read the bytecode and (possibly) compile it into machine code before executing it. The source code for all of them is [part of the hotspot](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/857e77fd668d/src). You probably just want to limit yourself to the interpreter and disable the compilers for initial work. If so, [this set of notes explain how the hotspot interpreter works](http://markmail.org/download.xqy?id=vn5olfue3yiwldjh&number=1).

Comment: yes i want to be limited to the interpreter only. no need to change the compiler. i just need to open the bytecode, replace some group of instructions with a new specific one (just like compression). and to make the interpreter able to understand (and replace ) my added instruction.

Comment: @adeeliqbal I don't understand the phrase "i just need to open the bytecode". Do you want to modify the bytecode generated by javac? Or take the bytecode generated by javac and further process it?

Comment: Yes. The complete task is to modify the bytecode generated by javac and further process it in embedded systems.